# Cannot set bar chart width for specific data, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It's just makes me crazy and I try to solve this problem 2 days but no success.

I try to create 4 [highchairs stackedbar](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked). Each on per line.

Each chart has different width based on value.

For example if

```
series = [{name: 'Jane',data: [100]}, {name: 'Joe',data: [50]}]
```

so the `width` of chart container should be `150` (100+50)

I created the demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr14fx8c/)

[image]

**Why the 3<sup>d</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> chart do not reach red border (wrapper) like 1 and 2?**

What I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
$(function() {

   var template = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      backgroundColor: null,
      borderWidth: 0,           
      margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      width: 10,
      height: 40,
      style: {
        overflow: 'visible'
      },
      skipClone: true
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples'],
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      lineColor: 'transparent',
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      startOnTick: false,
      endOnTick: false,
      tickPositions: []
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
     // max:114,
      gridLineColor: 'transparent',
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: null
      }
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: []
  };

  var ch1 = clone(template);
  ch1.chart.width  = 150;
  ch1.yAxis.max  = 150;
  ch1.series = [{name: 'Jane',data: [100]}, {name: 'Joe',data: [50]}]

   var ch2 = clone(template);
   ch2.chart.width  = 100;
   ch2.yAxis.max  = 100;
   ch2.series = [{name: 'Jane',data: [68]}, {name: 'Joe',data: [32]}]

    var ch3 = clone(template);
    ch3.chart.width  = 170;
    ch3.yAxis.max  = 170;
    ch3.series = [{name: 'Jane',data: [20]}, {name: 'Joe',data: [150]}]

     var ch4 = clone(template);
     ch4.chart.width  = 18;
     ch4.yAxis.max  = 18;
     ch4.series = [{name: 'Jane',data: [4]}, {name: 'Joe',data: [12]}]




  $('#container1').highcharts(ch1);
  $('#container2').highcharts(ch2);
  $('#container3').highcharts(ch3);
  $('#container4').highcharts(ch4);


  function clone(obj) {
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
        return obj;    
    var temp = new obj.constructor(); 
    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);    
    return temp;
}
});
```

**EDIT**

I think I found the problem but not the solution.

This is a [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv1j6546/)

[image]

In first chart the value is 150 and it fill all 3 ticks where each tick has 50.

On other hand, the second chart has value 170 and in fill 3 ticks and start 4th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the axis extends to match the `tickInterval`, whether or not you set a max value.

If you display your y axis labels, you'll see the cause more clearly.

To solve, set the `endOnTick` and `maxPadding` properties, and skip setting the axis max.

**Code:**

```
yAxis: {
  endOnTick: false,
  maxPadding: 0
}
```

**Example:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rr14fx8c/1/

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: yay, OMG, you my hero :) So easy when you know how to solve it

Comment: @snaggs of course, it seems like you could make it much less complicated by putting this all in one chart. I assume you are doing more with than is evident in the example, but perhaps it can be simplified still?

Comment: Each chart (bar) wrapped by additional data so I cannot put all in one